# Como trabalhar com valores que excedem muito o valor limite do long (64 bits)?

Tags: java, c, ciência-da-computação

Como é armazenado e realizado operações com números que excedem os valores limites do tipo `long` e `double`? Como são feitas as quatro operações primárias com estes números (soma, subtração, multiplicação e divisão)?

> **Contexto**

É comum a maioria das linguagens de programação suportarem tipos `long` e `double` (ambos utilizam uma palavra de 64 bits) entretanto em Super computadores (como os que fazem os cálculos de bombas atômicas e processamento de dados meteorológicos e astronômicos) que possuem milhares de núcleos de processamento e TBs de memoria Ram trabalhando de forma concorrente provavelmente devem trabalhar com valores que excedem e muito os valores suportados `long` e `double`.

> Exemplo de valores que excedem e muito os valores suportados `long` e
>   `double`.

- googol
- googolplex
- mol (unidade química)
- `Long.MAX_VALUE * Long.MAX_VALUE * Long.MAX_VALUE` (**JAVA**)
- googolplex * googolplex

Quais seriam possíveis soluções em `C` (muito desempenho) e `Java` (muito conhecida)

Comment: Amigos, Quero sugerir apenas para acrescentar o artigo, um dos melhores que já li sobre este problema: LINK: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Programacao-com-numeros-inteiros-gigantes

Comment: O tamanho dos números utilizados não tem a ver com a "potência" do computador. Os cálculos de simulação em super-computadores são feitos em geral com floats de 64bits (double) - e nada impede que mesmo um netbook tenha programas que usem números de precisão arbitrária em qualquer programa, como pode-se ver nas respostas abaixo.

A questão é que de fato, o hardware nas CPUs é otimizado para realizar operaçẽos com float de 32 ou 64 bits - acima disso (em geral) a conta tem que ser feita em Software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como os números grandes são representados e armazenados vai depender da sua linguagem de programação. Em linguagens como **C** e **Java**, o máximo que elas lhe oferecem são bibliotecas que implementem números gigantes. Já em linguagens como **Python3** e **Haskell**, você não precisa se preocupar em "estourar" uma variável porque o número é muito grande. Exemplos de uso:

---

**Em C**, utilizando a biblioteca [gmp](https://gmplib.org):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    mpz_t a, b;
    mpz_init_set_str (a, "987654321987654321000000000", 10);
    mpz_init_set_str (b, "987654321987654321000000000", 10);
    mpz_mul (a, a, b); // a = a * b

    printf("%s\n", mpz_get_str (NULL, 10, a));
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado: `975461059740893157555403139789971041000000000000000000`.

**Observação:** o arquivo `.c` deve ser compilado com o seguinte comando para incluir a biblioteca gmp: `gcc ARQUIVO.c -lgmp -lm`.

---

**Em Java**, utilizando a classe [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("987654321987654321000000000");
        BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("987654321987654321000000000");

        BigInteger produto = b1.multiply(b2);

        System.out.println(produto);
    }
}
```

Resultado: `975461059740893157555403139789971041000000000000000000`.

---

**Em Haskell**, com suporte nativo:

```
Prelude> 987654321987654321000000000 * 987654321987654321000000000
975461059740893157555403139789971041000000000000000000
```

---

**Em Python3**, também com suporte nativo:

```
>>> 987654321987654321000000000 * 987654321987654321000000000
975461059740893157555403139789971041000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 5):

Em Java utilize a classe [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Ela tem tamanho arbitrário.

Em C vai ter que escolher uma biblioteca não padrão ou implementar por conta própria. A [GMPLib](https://gmplib.org/) tem uma implementação conhecida.

A multiplicação se dá pelo método [`multiply()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply-java.math.BigInteger-):

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("12345678901234567890");
BigInteger y = new BigInteger("9876543210");
x.multiply(y);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sWSU47). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jpqknper-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/BigInteger.java).

Comment: Entendo ela esta limitado ao tamanho da Ram ou da Ram + HD (paginação)?

Comment: Até onde eu sei, sim.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de definição e multiplicação com ambas as soluções para resposta ficar completa?

Comment: @Ricardo feito!

Answer (score 4):

Existem várias formas de armazenar e efetuar cálculos com números de precisão arbitrária.

Acredito que o exemplo mais simples é armazenar os dígitos que compõe o número em uma string e fazer os cálculos "praticamente" da mesma forma que fazemos
a conta manualmente, porém, essa forma simples não oferece um desempenho muito bom.

Segue um exemplo prático, comentado e **bem simples** em `C` de como efetuar uma **soma** com números arbitrários:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Tamanho do buffer
#define TAMANHO_MAXIMO  100000

// Retorna o máximo de 2 números
#define MAX(x, y)   ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))

int soma(const char *num1, const char *num2, char resultado[], int max)
{
    int d1, d2, i1, i2, r, soma;
    int vai_um = 0;
    int res;

    // Índices dos números. Começa a soma a partir da unidade
    i1 = strlen(num1);
    i2 = strlen(num2);

    // Retorna o tamanho do resultado a ser impresso
    res = max - (MAX(i1, i2) + 1);

    // Índice do resultado
    r = max - 2;

    d1 = d2 = soma = 0;

    // Efetua a soma dígito a dígito
    for (;;) {
        // Se terminou finaliza o looping
        if (i1 <= 0 && i2 <= 0)
            break;

        // Obtém os dois dígitos
        d1 = i1-- <= 0 ? 0 : num1[i1] - 48;
        d2 = i2-- <= 0 ? 0 : num2[i2] - 48;

        // Soma os dígitos e o "vai um" se houver
        soma = d1 + d2 + vai_um;

        // Se a soma for maior que o dígito nove, "guarda" o "vai um"
        if (soma > 9) {
            vai_um = 1;
            soma = soma - 10;
        } else {
            // se for menor que 9, o "vai um" é zero
            vai_um = 0;
        }

        // Armazena dígito calculado
        resultado[r--] = soma + 48;
    };
    // retorna o tamanho a ser impresso
    return res;
}


int main()
{
    // Números
    char *n1 = "77843828938721973129372914798658749876459670949872346284631267542726289473294723948102389208120398347289347239472912345673414723947328947329472394810238920812039834728934723947298309563680458650468804968450685604586065486450684508654068059482309128301238019238120334332984732947492384772394723947329473294793248012983012318";
    char *n2 = "289473294723948102389208120398347289347239472912345673414723947328262894732947239481023892081203983472893947329472394810238920812039834728934723947298309563680458650468804968450685604586065486450684508654068059482309128301238019238120334332984732947492384772394723947329473294793248012983012318";

    // Resultado
    char resultado[TAMANHO_MAXIMO];
    // Tamanho do resulltado
    size_t r;

    // Preenche o resultado com 0
    memset(resultado, 0, TAMANHO_MAXIMO);

    // Coloca NULL no final da string
    resultado[TAMANHO_MAXIMO - 1] = NULL;
    printf("SOMA=%s\n + %s\n = \n\n", n1, n2);

    // Chama a função soma e informa o tamanho máximo do buffer
    r = soma(n1, n2, &resultado[0], TAMANHO_MAXIMO);

    printf("%s\n", &resultado[r]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Após a execução, a saída é:

```
SOMA=778438289387219731293729147986587498764596709498723462846312675427262894732
94723948102389208120398347289347239472912345673414723947328947329472394810238920
81203983472893472394729830956368045865046880496845068560458606548645068450865406
80594823091283012380192381203343329847329474923847723947239473294732947932480129
83012318
 + 28947329472394810238920812039834728934723947291234567341472394732826289473294
72394810238920812039834728939473294723948102389208120398347289347239472983095636
80458650468804968450685604586065486450684508654068059482309128301238019238120334
332984732947492384772394723947329473294793248012983012318
 =

77843828938721973129372914798948223171183619052261554405029614832073528946207069
62151711315544866124202229447895393623775461870742022289465894478962047784162407
96694578694478945966191273609173009376099369013712091721309729013690173081361189
64618256602476038476240668665969465894984769544789447894658946589586496025966024
636
```

Ne exemplo acima, o tamanho do buffer está limitado a constante `TAMANHO_MAXIMO`,
porém, em uma biblioteca real, ele pode ser alocado dinamicamente.

As demais operações (subtração, multiplicação, divisão) são feitas de forma semelhante.

Existem várias técnicas para otimizar esse tipo de operação, por exemplo:

- alterar a base do número para uma base maior (ex: base 16, 64 ou 256), pois cada dígito ocupa um espaço menor de memória
- guardar a operação "vai um" em um vetor e aplicá-lo em apenas um looping ao final da operação (utilizado principalmente na multiplicação)

---

Para maiores informações sobre operações com números arbitrários e otimização (em inglês):

[The Art of Computer Programming - Vol 2](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/books.html)

[Numerical Recipes Home Page](http://numerical.recipes/)

Answer (score 1):

A multiplicacao pode ser feita por partes.
Divides o numero em bocados mais pequenos, multiplicas esses bocados entre si (com regras) e finalmente somas os produtos todos, com regras.

Por exemplo, para multiplicar 1234567 por 321 podes dividir os numeros em pedacos de 2 algarismos (base 100). Agora multiplicas os pedacos de cada numero

```
1 * 3 = 3 (base ^ 4)
1 * 21 = 21 (base ^ 3)
23 * 3 = 69 (base ^ 3)
23 * 21 = 483 (base ^ 2)
45 * 3 = 135 (base ^ 2)
45 * 21 = 945 (base ^ 1)
67 * 3 = 201 (base ^ 1)
67 * 21 = 1407 (base ^ 0)
```

E agora se somares estes produtos mantendo atencao as bases, obtens

```
3, 21+69, 483+135, 945+201, 1407
3, 90, 618, 1146, 1407
3, 90+6, 18+11, 46+14, 07
3, 96, 29, 60, 07
396296007                          = 1234567 * 321
```

Com computadores isto 'e facil de fazer em base 256, por exemplo.

Basicamente esta 'e a forma que eu aprendi na escola :-)