# Potencia utilizando recursão

Tags: c

Pois bem, estou fazendo um código básico em C, não sou muito bom com essa linguagem, estou aprendendo ela, embora eu já tenha visto porem não utilizado muito. Ele consiste em fazer a operação de potencia através de recursão.
O problema se encontra na saída quando a potencia é superior a 10

//Input:
//6 20

//Output:
//-1190133760

O codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int potencia(A, N){
    int x;
    if(N == 0){
    return 1;
    }

    return A*potencia(A, N-1);

}

int main(){
    int A, N;
    scanf("%d %d", &A &N);
    printf("%d\n", potencia(A, N));

}
```

como pode ser visto, a saída é um numero totalmente absurdo, porém eu não o porque e nem como isso acontece alguém pode me explicar e se possível explicar  oque tenho que fazer para gerar a saída certa?

Comment: O problema não tem nada a ver com a potência, e sim com o fato de você estar estourando a capacidade numérica do tipo `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu problema aqui é o tipo das variáveis que você está utilizando. Em **C**, o tipo nativo **int** aceita valores no máximo até `2147483647`, por isso que quando você tenta calcular `6 ^ 15` o resultado não faz sentido.

Uma solução é utilizar o tipo **unsigned long long int**, o qual aceita valores entre `0` e `18446744073709551615`. Seu algoritmo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
# include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int potencia(unsigned long long A, unsigned long long N){
    if(N == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return A*potencia(A, N-1);
}

int main(){
    unsigned long long int A, N;
    scanf("%llu %llu", &A, &N);
    printf("%llu\n", potencia(A, N));
}
```

Execução dele:

```
$ gcc main.c && ./a.out
6 20
3656158440062976
```

**Observações:** o tipo **unsigned long long** existe apenas a partir da especificação [C99 <sup>en</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). Se você estiver executando esse código em uma versão anterior do **C**, vale dar uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115809/41113) do SO de como lidar com números gigantescos, e [nessa biblioteca](https://gmplib.org/) de números gigantescos para **C**.

Comment: `unsigned long long` 'e uma "novidade" do C99, Pode nao existir na implementacao do Albion.

Comment: eu estou utilizando o cloud 9, lá deu certo vlw cara ainda estou aprendendo a documentação do C

Comment: @pmg. Albion acabou já marcando como correta porque deu certo, mas eu já tinha editado para deixar uma observação sobre seu comentário. Vlws.