# Como criar variável para conter um número com milhões de dígitos?

Tags: variáveis, memória, inteiros

Vi uma reportagem sobre a descoberta de um número primo que contém 22 milhões de dígitos. Como seria possível uma variável conter um número, por exemplo, com 100 milhões de dígitos.

Comment: Esses números normalmente não tem "um monte de dígitos". Teriam se fossem escritos "por extenso", mas a representação deles é curtinha assim: 2^216091-1. Hipoteticamente, se você precisasse mesmo trabalhar com vários números desses dígito a dígito, não precisaria de variáveis, mas sim de um stream, que pode ser em disco, assim poderia "correr" por ele para fazer operaçoes, e nem precisaria ter tudo na memória. Se quiser o número do exemplo acima por extenso, eis o link: http://bigprimes.net/pages/archive/mersenne/M31.txt - Peguei esse como exemplo por ser curtinho, apenas 65050 dígitos.

Comment: Acredito que [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115809/41113) esteja relacionada à sua e possa trazer algumas explicações também.

Answer (score 5):

Para colocar um número muito grande em memória é simples: basta guardar os dígitos como uma grande `string`, ou o que é mais perto da máquina, o número em formato binário como um array de `byte`.

O que você provavelmente está perguntando é como colocar esse número em memória da forma que ele se comporte como um "número comum". Para esses casos existem estruturas de dados ou classes que guardam o número em memória numa representação interna qualquer (provavelmente `byte[]`), e que contém métodos públicos que permitem manipular essa massa de dados como se fosse um número "puro".

Dê uma olhada: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html (Java) e https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx (C#).

Outras linguagens terão classes ou estruturas semelhantes. Na verdade, se procurar por `BigInteger` ou `BigDecimal`, verá que tem várias implementações diferentes desse tipo de classe, feitas por programadores, nas mais variadas linguagens. Ou seja, é possível criar esse tipo de "número grande" na mão, sem depender de detalhes específicos da linguagem de programação que está trabalhando. No final é apenas código que emula a mesma coisa que se espera de números comuns.

Answer (score 4):

Embora tecnicamente seja possível colocar o número em uma variável, dificilmente isto é feito. Normalmente aloca-o na memória e a variável apenas aponta para ele. Pelo menos isto seria necessário se realmente precisar guardar todos os dígitos. Nem sempre é (vide comentário do Bacco). Tem formas de representar o número sem guardar todos seus dígitos.

Existem várias formas de armazenar todos os dígitos também. Uma bem óbvia seria fazer o mesmo que se faz para guardar um texto de 100 milhões de caracteres (uma `String`). Só que neste caso seriam apenas dígitos numéricos.

Todas as técnicas normalmente terão que usar algum *array* de bytes. A codificação deste *array* pode variar de acordo com cada necessidade. Mesmo que o número tenha alguma codificação específica.

Muitas vezes é necessário pensar além da memória. Se o número é muito grande pode não caber na memória. Mesmo tendo a possibilidade da memória virtual, pode ser útil procurar uma solução pensada para trabalhar com esse número em disco e ter mais controle de como isto é feito.

Algumas linguagens possuem um tipo próprio que já faz isto. O tipo costuma chamar-se [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) ou algo parecido.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelos esclarecimentos!! Vou dar um olhada nos links e pesquisar as dicas dadas.